# SSIS error 2008R2

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, ssis-2008

I am encountering a weird error when I execute a SSIS packages through SQL Agent.
Error encountered is:-

> The step did not generate any output.  The return value was unknown. 
>   The process exit code was -1073741819.  The step failed.

But when I run this package manually I don't face any issue. I would appreciate if anyone can help me out with this error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give more details please? What does the package do? Do you know on which component/task is it failing?

Comment: Packages have data flow task and Execute SQL task(To call store procedure) and as I said I don't have any problems when I run this package manually and it fails with the error stated above only when I execute from SQL Agent

Comment: permissions? Are your connections set up as trusted, and if so does the SQL Agent Account have adequate permissions the same (as far as the package needs) as the local user when you run manually? For your SQL task that calls a stored procedure is there any possibility that it will return a null when you are counting on it to return value(s)?  Are you using a script task or a command task that might not be providing the correct output of success?

Comment: Please include the output of the SSIS execution report - the SQL Agent errors are generally completely unhelpful. To get to it, connect to the database server hosting the SSIS packages, then go Integration Services Catalogs->SSISDB->[Your project]->Projects, right click on the name of your project, then click Reports->Standard Reports->All Executions.